# Code blocks for checking checkbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP and C# and need some advice on C# code blocks inside ASPX. I have tried changing label text depend on checkbox value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True"></asp:CheckBox>

<% if (CheckBox1.Checked==True)   {%> 
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="Checked"></asp:Label>
<%  } else {%>  
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="Not Checked"></asp:Label>
<%  }%>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not working and i not sure if this is right way of doing this.

Comment: Look at this, It will work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to separate your markup and code into 2 different files (eg Default.aspx & Default.aspx.cs ).
To change label text try to handle page's load event.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True"></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Label1.Text = CheckBox1.Checked ? "Checked" : "Not checked";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because true is spelled with lowercase only.

your code works fine, im assuming you are not using an IDE because it would have told you that `True` is not defined. you have to change it to `true`

```
<% if (CheckBox1.Checked==true)   {%>
```

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, you will have to use javascript or jquery for the.. since aspx is a server side language, it will have no control on the web page once it loads.